# SQL Parameter Syntax: Declare @Parameter [dbo].[Table]

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, parameters, sql-server-2012

I am working with a stored procedure that has a parameter syntax that I am unfamiliar with.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[sproc_GetAppSetting]
    @AppSettingIDs [dbo].[SomeTable] READONLY,
    @AppSectionID INT,
    @KeyName varchar(255)
AS
SELECT
    as.AppSettingSettingID,
    as.Value,
    as.ConfigID
FROM
    AppSetting as WITH(NOLOCK)
JOIN
    @AppSettingIDs asIds ON asIds.Val = as.ConfigID
WHERE
    as.AppSectionID = @AppSectionID
    AND as.Status = 'A'
    AND as.Name = @KeyName
```

My question is about the line:

```
@AppSettingIDs [dbo].[SomeTable] READONLY
```

It appears that this variable is being used as a reference to a table later in the query:

```
JOIN
    @AppSettingIDs asIds ON asIds.Val = as.ConfigID
```

The table `[dbo].[SomeTable]` does not exist in the database I am working with. Further more, when I extract the `@AppSettingIDs` declaration line as an attempt to understand what is stored in the variable outside of the context of the stored procedure, I get a SQL error:

```
DECLARE @AppSettingIDs  [dbo].[SomeTable]
```

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
>   Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type dbo.SomeTable. Parameter or variable '@AppSettingIDs' has an invalid data type.

Can some one clarify what that parameter declaration is doing & how I might be able to replicate it outside of a stored procedure?

Comment: that is not a table; it is a user-defined table type; if you have ssms, expand your db --> programmability -->types -->  user defined table types, you should be abel to see this parameter defined table there

Comment: @techspider Thanks, I was able to find the table type. That should put me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@AppSettingIDs [dbo].[SomeTable] READONLY
```

This means that you are declaring a variable using a user defined Table Type.

Your variable `@AppSettingIDs` can hold many rows as per your need. The structure of the variable is very similar to your User defined Table Type since it is copy of user defined Table Type.

Refer the screenshot to find the location of user defined table types in your database.

[image]